Are there any tools like Coh-metrix and T-Scan for other languages?
Coh-Metrix and T-Scan are tools that access complexity of texts based on linguistic features present in the text. Specifically, these tools are designed for English and Dutch. I was wondering if any such tools exist for other languages. Does anybody know of place with an overview of such tools for various languages?
